# Moshe Rabbainu & Rabbi Shimon Bar Yochai

Tags: sources-mekorot, moshe-rabbeinu, kabbalat-hatorah, rabbi-shimon-bar-yochai

Does anybody know the source of the story where Moshe Rabbainu was in shomayim to receive the Torah, but the Malachim didn't want the soul of Rabbi Shimon Bar Yochai to descend to give the hidden parts of the Torah.

I have seen sources regarding the fight between Malachim and Moshe in regard to what is in it, but I could not find the one with Rabbi Shimon Bar Yochai. There is definitely a source. I just can not seem to remember where it is.

Comment: "There is definitely a source" Please [edit] to explain why you are so confident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are referring to an idea that I saw quoted by Chabad ([3rd question here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2869559/jewish/Vedibarta-Bam-Lag-BaOmer.htm))

> When Moshe went up to heaven to take the Torah, the angels opposed him
>   (see Gemara [Shabbat 88b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.88b.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). After he succeeded in proving that the
>   Torah is meant for man and not for angels, they still insisted that
>   the esoteric teachings of the Torah (penimiut haTorah) remain with
>   them. The one who revealed the esoteric teachings of Torah was Rabbi
>   Shimon bar Yochai.

See also end of first point [here](http://www.shuvubonim.org/pray3.html).